# Excel VBA hides rows after execution

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small code that refreshes the data, then it selects and unhides all rows, when this is finished it Displays a MSGBx that the refresh is complete. This is what my code should do, no more or less. But after the execution it hides all the 1500+ rows that it had just refreshed. Any suggestions how to disable this? I have tried delays and unhiding it multiple times, but the hiding happens after the execution...

My Code:

```
Private Sub RefreshButton_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Cells.Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Cells.Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Go through this code step-by-step (using F8) to see each step of execution. Check if there is other code than this procedure executed (eg by any event). Check if there are any events defined in your workbook and post their code too.

Comment: Also the 3 lines (From .Select to .Hidden) can be written in 1 line `Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Comment: Are you pausing for 5 seconds for effect - or are you hoping your `.RefreshAll` has finished after 5 seconds? If the settings are set up for refreshes in the background, use a `DoEvents` to halt execution until the `.RefreshAll` has completed.

Comment: @Peh ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll hides the rows, With F8 i am giving it time to finish and execute the code succesfully. I think the Application.Wait is just freezing everything for 5 Seconds

Comment: @CLR I tried using the Application.Wait because DoEvents didn't work.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Thanks for the suggestion, the macro i recorded made .Select to .Hidden.